# Replace function in prototype attributes iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs

I am trying to replace a hyphen in all attributes

```
<a href="/page" id="someId" data-country="north-america" data-state="north-dakota">North Dakota</a>
```

like so:

```
var el = document.getElementById('someId');
Array.prototype.slice.call(el.attributes).forEach(function(item) {
   item.value.replace('-','_');
   console.log(item.value);
});
```

Can't quite figure out why it's not actually replacing the hyphen with an underscore. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new String, it does not alter the original String. Just assing the new value and you're done.

```
item.value = item.value.replace('-','_');
```

Quoted from the MDN documentation:

> This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.